# Substitute shortest match of pattern in filename

Tags: bash

I have files with the following filename pattern:

```
C14_1_S1_R1_001_copy1.fastq.gz
```

That I would like to be renamed this way:

```
C14_1_S1_R1.fastq.gz
```

I have tested unsuccessfully the following pattern replacement strategy:

```
for f in *.fastq.gz; do echo mv "$f" "${f/_*./_}"; done
```

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: `rename 's/_[0-9]{3}_[^.]*//'` may do your work.

Answer (score 4):

Your original filename has several underscore characters but you only want to remove from the second to last underscore.  In that case, try:

```
 mv "$f" "${f%_*_*}.fastq.gz"
```

Consider a directory with these files:

```
$ ls -1
C14_1_S1_R1_001_copy1.fastq.gz
C15_1_S1_R1_001_copy1.fastq.gz
```

If we run our loop and then run a new `ls`, we see the changed filenames:

```
$ for f in ./*.fastq.gz; do mv "$f" "${f%_*_*}.fastq.gz"; done
$ ls -1
C14_1_S1_R1.fastq.gz
C15_1_S1_R1.fastq.gz
```

The key here is that `${var%word}` is *suffix removal* and it matches the **shortest** possible suffix that matches the glob `word`.  Thus, `${f%_*_*}` removes the second-to-last underscore character and everything after it.  `${f%_*_*}.fastq.gz` removes the second-to-last underscore character and everything after and then restores your desired suffix of `.fastq.gz`.

Answer (score 1):

With regex using the `=~` test operator and `BASH_REMATCH`

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for file in *.fastq.gz; do
  if [[ $file =~ ^(.+)(_[[:digit:]]+_copy.*[^\.])(\.fastq\.gz)$ ]]; then
    echo mv -v "$file" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
  fi
done
```

---

Basically it just split the `C14_1_S1_R1_001_copy1.fastq.gz` into three parts.

- `BASH_REMATCH[1]` has `C14_1_S1_R1`
- `BASH_REMATCH[2]` has `_001_copy1`
- `BASH_REMATCH[3]` has `.fastq.gz`
- Remove the `echo` if you're ok with the output so the files can be renamed.

Answer (score 1):

```
str="C14_1_S1_R1_001_copy1.fastq.gz"

front=$(echo "${str}" | cut -d'_' -f1-4)
back=$(echo "${str}" | cut --complement -d'.' -f1)
echo "${front}.${back}"
```